# Qual a diferença entre essas expressões?

Tags: c, formatação, int

No manual da srand `man srand` diz que srand tem como parâmetro um `unsigned int`, porém ao utilizar sem cast o compilador não reclama. Tem alguma possibilidade de dar errado caso não utilizar com cast `(unsigned int)` ? Se sim, quais os possíveis erros ?

Um exemplo, comparando as duas linhas de código abaixo:

```
srand(time(NULL));
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

Comment: Compile com *warning* ligado. *warning* é erro que permite compilar mas ainda é erro. É um erro que você não precisa se preocupar em toda compilação, mas quando finalizar o programa é um erro que não pode existir.

Comment: @bigown Eu sempre compilo usando `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -o saida entrada.c` e nunca deixo meus códigos finalizados com warning, a não ser em casos muito extremos. Mas neste caso, o compilador não acusou nenhum warning, foi isso que eu quis dizer em "...porém ao utilizar sem cast o compilador não reclama...", reclama, no caso, seria o warning, desculpa não ter explicitado isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele esta fazendo o cast implicitamente, o que nao tem problemas em alguns casos.

Por exemplo:

```
int x = 3;
double y = 4.5;
x = x + y;
```

O que acontece nesses casos e o seguinte:

```
1. Na soma de `x` com `y`, `x` e promovido para `double` e a soma acontece como se ambos fossem desse tipo;
2. O resultado da soma, 7.5, e convertido de volta para `int`, ja que `x` e do tipo inteiro.
```

Normalmente, o compilador faz essas operacoes implicitamente. Voce tambem pode fazer explicitamente, por exemplo:

```
int x = 65;
printf("%c\n", (char)x);
```

Agora, nos interpretamos `x` como `char` para imprimir, entao o seu valor da `A`.

Ha, contudo, casos em que esses conversoes implicitas dao errado, principalmente com ponteiros.

Comment: Mas e se ao invés de `time(NULL)` eu tivesse uma variável do tipo `int` que tivesse em seu conteúdo um valor negativo ?

Comment: ele simplesmente iria interpretar o valor como positivo. lembre-se de que no PC não existem valores negativos, é só uma outra interpretação do valor em binário.

Comment: Para ele interpretar como valores positivo, ele vai utilizar que método de conversão ? Seria complemento a 2 ou alguma outra coisa específica ?

Comment: Bom, espero que caiba aqui. Um numero no computador sempre tem uma representacao em binario, certo? Vamos assumir que nosso computador tenha uma representacao com 8 bits apenas, ou seja, 8 `0` ou `1`. Por exemplo, o numero `7` seria: `00000111`. Para representar os negativos a gente usa uma maracutaia: o bit mais a esquerda, nesse caso o 8o, vai ser `1` se o numero for negativo. Logo, `-7` e `10000111`. Espero que tenha ficado mais claro.

Comment: Então se for 8 bits para representar os inteiros, iria de -128 até 127 ? Quando o complemento a 2 é utilizado ?

Comment: isso, perfeito. o complemento de 2 de um número é como o negativo dele.

Answer (score 1):

Ao adicionares o header que contem a declaração da função `srand()` (o header `stdlib.h`) o compilador fica a saber qual o tipo do parametro.

Depois ele converte o tipo que usaste no tipo requerido, se possível. Se não for possível dá uma mensagem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    srand(42); // ok
    srand(4.2); // ok, conversao de 4.2 para 4
    srand(srand); // NOT ok! nao é possivel converter pointers para unsigned
}
```

Se removeres o `#include` já estão todos mal embora o compilador não se queixe